# How to drag text file into text-area to show contents using Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to build a feature where a user can either type into a text-area or drag a text file into the text-area where it will insert the content into the textarea.

I couldn't find any library that achieves this.

So for starters, I'm just trying to be able to drag a file into a textarea and perform an action. Is there an angular function/action for dragging a file to an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something similar with images, but the concept should be fairly the same...

I would use a directive on the element and bind to a drag and drop event then use **FileReader.readAsText()** to read the contents (make sure you check file types and what not).

**HTML**

```
<div class="drop-zone" plkr-file-drop-zone content="text">
  <textarea>{{text}}</textarea>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.text = "";
 })
 .directive('plkrFileDropZone', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {content:'='},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.content = "drop a .txt file here";

            var processDragOverOrEnter;

            processDragOverOrEnter = function (event) {
                if (event !== null) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
                return false;
            };

            element.bind('dragover', processDragOverOrEnter);
            element.bind('dragenter', processDragOverOrEnter);
            element.bind('drop', handleDropEvent);

            function insertText(loadedFile) {

                scope.content = loadedFile.target.result;
                scope.$apply();
            }

            function handleDropEvent(event) {

                if (event !== null) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = insertText;
                reader.readAsText(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);

            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here's a working version...

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/D8hu32H0tPYnx64ZjW57?p=preview)

** I only tested this in Chrome :)